# Camel Quartz vs. Quartz 2 - different core versions

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

When going to implement Quartz 2 I noticed the latest release was 2.25.4. However, the latest Quartz release is 3.7.4. How can quartz2 be on an older Camel core than Quartz?

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-quartz</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-quartz2</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the Camel 3.0 upgrade guide, where v2 components has been renamed.

In Camel v2 there was an old version of quartz v1 and then later quartz v2 was released and we then had to create a new Camel component for it, e.g., camel-quartz2.

In Camel 3 we drop many of those very old components, e.g., quartz v1 is dropped. And then the components are renamed to have "normal" name again.

*[Apache Camel 2.x to 3.0 Migration Guide](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html)*

Comment: Amazing. This is exactly what I was looking for and was hoping this was the case!