# Is quartz from camel 3 really the same thing as quartz2 from camel 2?

Tags: apache-camel, quartz

I am trying to upgrade camel from 2 to 3. I had previously had camel-quartz2 from camel 2 included in my pom.xml, but because [quartz2 is apparently called quartz now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68116938/camel-quartz-vs-quartz-2-different-core-versions), I have added this to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-quartz</artifactId>
  <version>3.17.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I removed quartz2.

The problem is that I now receive this error.

```
Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'startDelayedSeconds' of bean class [org.apache.camel.component.quartz.QuartzComponent]: Bean property 'startDelayedSeconds' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

I looked and saw that the the StartDelayedSeconds method is not part of [quartz](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.17.x/quartz-component.html) as it was with [quartz2](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/quartz2-component.html). Does this mean that they are really not the same? If this is the case, then why is the [newest version of quartz2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-quartz2) so far behind the [newest version of quartz](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-quartz). Is there some sort of workaround that I could do, or some part of quartz that I should use?

Comment: If there is any clarification needed or something that I did not include, please let me know. I am still trying to figure out what stuff is important/relevant from what I can list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From the Came 3 migration guide:**

> The **quartz2 component has been renamed to quartz**, and it’s corresponding component package from org.apache.camel.component.quartz2 to org.apache.camel.component.quartz. The supported scheme is now quartz.
>
> **Source:** https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3-migration-guide.html

When I run command `mvn dependency:tree` with project that contains camel-quartz dependency I get the following:

```bash
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-quartz:jar:3.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.15:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.zaxxer:HikariCP-java7:jar:2.4.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.5.5:compile
```

Based on that I would say its safe to assume that camel-quartz in camel 3.x uses quartz scheduler version 2.x. The option `StartDelayedSeconds` has likely been moved or changed during one of the major or minor version changes.

A lot of components have gone through some changes to use more up to date libraries and to make them easier to use or just consistent with other components.

[Edit] Regarding the StartDelayedSeconds option found this from one of the [many](https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3x-upgrade-guide.html) Apache Camel upgrade guides.

> UPGRADING CAMEL 3.14 TO 3.15
> Removed the option startDelaySeconds as this does not work correctly and causes problems if in use.
>
> **Source:** [Upgrading camel 3.14 TO 3.15](https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3x-upgrade-guide-3_15.html#_camel_quartz)

Comment: Do you know of any way to find what changes those specifically were or how to find where things were moved to. I am looking, but I am just not finding anything good.

Comment: According to [this](https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3x-upgrade-guide-3_15.html#_camel_quartz) it was removed in camel 3.15 as it doesn't work and may cause problems if used.